# How to solve a NotImplementedError from nltk.classify ClassifierI?

Tags: python, nltk

I am new to programming, but have looked at my code over and over and can't see any mistakes. I don't know how proceed any more because this error pops up no matter what I try. I'll post the full code here.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
import nltk
import random
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
import pickle
from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB,BernoulliNB
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression, SGDClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC, LinearSVC, NuSVC
from nltk.classify import ClassifierI
from statistics import mode 

class VoteClassifier(ClassifierI):
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

        def classify(self, features):
            votes = []
            for c in self._classifiers:
                v = c.classify(features)
                votes.append(v)
            return mode(votes)


        def confidence(self, features):
            votes = []
            for c in self._classifiers:
                v = c.classify(features)
                votes.append(v)


            choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
            conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
            return conf


documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
             for category in movie_reviews.categories()
             for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]

random.shuffle(documents)

all_words = []

for w in movie_reviews.words():
        all_words.append(w.lower())

all_words = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)

word_features = list(all_words.keys())[:3000]

def find_features(document):
    words = set(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features

featuresets = [(find_features(rev), category) for (rev, category) in documents]

training_set = featuresets[:1900]
testing_set = featuresets[1900:]

# classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
classifier_f = open("naivebayes.pickle", "rb")
classifier = pickle.load(classifier_f)
classifier_f.close()

print("Original NaiveBayes accuracy percent:",(nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, testing_set))*100)
classifier.show_most_informative_features(10)

MNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(MultinomialNB())
MNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print("MNB_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(MNB_classifier, testing_set))*100)

BernoulliNB_classifier = SklearnClassifier(BernoulliNB())
BernoulliNB_classifier.train(training_set)
print("BernoulliNB_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(BernoulliNB_classifier, testing_set))*100)

LogisticRegression_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LogisticRegression())
LogisticRegression_classifier.train(training_set)
print("LogisticRegression_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LogisticRegression_classifier, testing_set))*100)

SGDClassifier_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SGDClassifier())
SGDClassifier_classifier.train(training_set)
print("SGDClassifier_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(SGDClassifier_classifier, testing_set))*100)

##SVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(SVC())
##SVC_classifier.train(training_set)
##print("SVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(SVC_classifier, testing_set))*100)

LinearSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(LinearSVC())
LinearSVC_classifier.train(training_set)
print("LinearSVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(LinearSVC_classifier, testing_set))*100)

NuSVC_classifier = SklearnClassifier(NuSVC())
NuSVC_classifier.train(training_set)
print("NuSVC_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(NuSVC_classifier, testing_set))*100)


voted_classifier = VoteClassifier(classifier,
                                  NuSVC_classifier,
                                  LinearSVC_classifier,
                                  SGDClassifier_classifier,
                                  MNB_classifier,
                                  BernoulliNB_classifier,
                                  LogisticRegression_classifier)

print("voted_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)
```

### I also tried raising a NotImplementedError exception on the class at the top but it did not change the output in Python.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code/test.py", line 109, in <module>
    print("voted_classifier accuracy percent:", (nltk.classify.accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set))*100)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/util.py", line 87, in accuracy
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs, l) in gold])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 77, in classify_many
    return [self.classify(fs) for fs in featuresets]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/api.py", line 56, in classify
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError
```

Comment: The library you are dependent on (nltk) is [generating the error](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/api.py#L56). You need to either use that library without calling that function, or raise an issue on their GitHub page.

Comment: Is it possible to override the error? The documentation has an "if overridden line" https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/api.py#L53

Comment: It appears that `self.classify_many` is just be a placeholder method that needs to be overridden elsewhere. I'm not familiar with the library but I doubt it will work if you simply override the error.

Comment: Your VoteClassifier class subclasses ClassifierI which is an abstract base class. It's purpose is to serve as a guide when making your own classifer and  to perform interface checking. Check the source for ClassifierI. https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/classify/api.py#L27
Any methods in ClassifierI which raise a NotImplementedError you must implement in your VoteClassifier.

Comment: Yes @101 is right. It looks like some circular spaghetti like thing is happening for `classify` vs `classify_many` =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, there's some bad spaghetti like code in the `ClassiferI` api that has `classify` calling `classify_many` when overriden. It might not be a bad thing when considering that the `ClassifierI` is strongly tied with the `NaiveBayesClassifier` object.

But for the particular use in the OP, the spaghetti code there isn't welcomed.

## TL;DR

Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/sklearn-nltk-voteclassifier

## In Long

From the traceback, the error is starts from `nltk.classify.util.accuracy()` calling the `ClassifierI.classify()`.

The `ClassifierI.classify()` is generally used to classify **ONE** document and the input is a dictionary of featureset with its binary values.

The `ClassifierI.classify_many()` is supposed to classify a **MULTIPLE** documents and the input is a list of dictionary of featureset with its binary values.

So the quick hack is to overwrite how the `accuracy()` function so that the `VotedClassifier` won't be dependent on the `ClassifierI` definition of `classify()` vs `classify_many()`. That would also mean that we don't inherit from `ClassifierI`. IMHO, if you don't need other functions other than `classify()`, there's no need to inherit the baggage that `ClassifierI` might come with:

```
def my_accuracy(classifier, gold):
    documents, labels = zip(*gold)
    predictions = classifier.classify_documents(documents)
    correct = [y == y_hat for y, y_hat in zip(labels, predictions)]
    if correct:
        return sum(correct) / len(correct)
    else:
        return 0

class VotraClassifier:
    def __init__(self, *classifiers):
        self._classifiers = classifiers

    def classify_documents(self, documents):
        return [self.classify_many(doc) for doc in documents]

    def classify_many(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)
        return mode(votes)

    def confidence(self, features):
        votes = []
        for c in self._classifiers:
            v = c.classify(features)
            votes.append(v)

        choice_votes = votes.count(mode(votes))
        conf = choice_votes / len(votes)
        return conf
```

Now if we call the new `my_accuracy()` with the new `VotedClassifier` object:

```
voted_classifier = VotraClassifier(nltk_nb, 
                                  NuSVC_classifier,
                                  LinearSVC_classifier,
                                  SGDClassifier_classifier,
                                  MNB_classifier,
                                  BernoulliNB_classifier,
                                  LogisticRegression_classifier)

my_accuracy(voted_classifier, testing_set)
```

[out]:

```
0.86
```

---

Note: There's certain randomness when it comes to shuffling the document and then holding out a set to test for the classifier accuracy.

My suggestion is to do the following instead of simple `random.shuffle(documents)`

- Repeat the experiments with various random seed.
- For each random seed, do a 10-fold cross validation.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)